# What am I doing wrong in this hamming code?

Tags: c++

I got college project for writing humming code. I give the below code which seems OK to me but I got 0 in my paper. Don't know what am I doing wrong here. Just before asking my professor can any I help me to find.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <math.h>

main(){
  int alp,k;
  do{
    cout<<"\n ****************************************************************";
    cout<<"\n \n";
    cout<<"\n WELCOME TO ERROR DETECTION AND CORRECTION";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n THE PROGRAM USES SINGLE BIT CORRECTION METHOD OFHAMMING CODES";
    cout<<"\n \n";
    cout<<"\n ****************************************************************";
    cout<<"\n \n \n 1.ALPHABET \n \n 2.NUMERIC \n \n 3.EXIT \n \n ENTER THECHOICE::";
    cin>> alp;
    if(alp==1){
      int num,err_bito,err_bitn;
      int bit[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
      int bits[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
      cout << "\n \n \n THIS IS CHARACTER ERROR DETECTION ANDCORRECTION PROGRAM";
      char one_char;
      int aq;
      cout << "\n \n \n \n Enter any a CHARACTER of upper or lower case: ";
      cin >> one_char;
      cout << "\n \n The character entered was : " << one_char << '\n';
      aq=(int) one_char;
      cout << "\n \n Its ASCII value is : " << aq << '\n';
      num=aq;
      bit[1]=num%2;
      int a;
      a=num-num%2;
      int b=a/2;
      bit[2]=b%2;
      a=b-b%2;
      b=a/2;
      bit[3]=b%2;
      a=b-b%2;
      b=a/2;
      bit[4]=b%2;
      a=b-b%2;
      b=a/2;
      bit[5]=b%2;
      a=b-b%2;
      b=a/2;
      bit[6]=b%2;
      a=b-b%2;
      b=a/2;
      bit[7]=b%2;
      a=b-b%2;
      b=a/2;
      bit[8]=b%2;
      a=b-b%2;
      b=a/2;
      bit[9]=b%2;
      a=b-b%2;
      b=a/2;
      bit[10]=b%2;
      a=b-b%2;
      b=a/2;
      bit[11]=b%2;
      a=b-b%2;
      b=a/2;
      cout << "\n \n The equivalent binary data is:";
      for( k=11;k>0;k--)
        cout << bit[k];
      cout << endl;
      int r1,r2,r3,r4,r1o,r2o,r3o,r4o,r1n,r2n,r3n,r4n;
      r1=r2=r3=r4=r1o=r2o=r3o=r4o=r1n=r2n=r3n=r4n=0;
      if(bit[1]==1){
        r1++;
        r2++;
      }
      if(bit[2]==1){
        r1++;
        r3++;
      }
      if(bit[3]==1){
        r2++;
        r3++;
      }
      if(bit[4]==1){
        r1++;
        r2++;
        r3++;
      }
      if(bit[5]==1){
        r1++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(bit[6]==1){
        r2++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(bit[7]==1){
        r1++;
        r2++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(bit[8]==1){
        r3++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(bit[9]==1){
        r1++;
        r3++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(bit[10]==1){
        r2++;
        r3++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(bit[11]==1){
        r1++;
        r2++;
        r3++;
        r4++;
      }
      r1o=r1%2;
      r2o=r2%2;
      r3o=r3%2;
      r4o=r4%2;
      cout<<"\n \n The REDUNDENT BITS are: ";
      cout << r1o << r2o << r3o << r4o << endl;
      r1=r2=r3=r4=0;
      int tx_data[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
      int rx_data[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
      cout <<"\n \n Data with REDUNDANT BITS are:";
      tx_data[15]=bit[11];
      cout << tx_data[15];
      tx_data[14]=bit[10];
      cout <<tx_data[14];
      tx_data[13]=bit[9];
      cout << tx_data[13];
      tx_data[12]=bit[8];
      cout << tx_data[12];
      tx_data[11]=bit[7];
      cout << tx_data[11];
      tx_data[10]=bit[6];
      cout << tx_data[10];
      tx_data[9]=bit[5];
      cout << tx_data[9];
      tx_data[8]=r4o;
      cout <<"("<<tx_data[8]<<")";
      tx_data[7]=bit[4];
      cout << tx_data[7];
      tx_data[6]=bit[3];
      cout << tx_data[6];
      tx_data[5]=bit[2];
      cout << tx_data[5];
      tx_data[4]=r3o;
      cout <<"("<< tx_data[4]<<")";
      tx_data[3]=bit[1];
      cout << tx_data[3];
      tx_data[2]=r2o;
      cout <<"("<< tx_data[2]<<")";
      tx_data[1]=r1o;
      cout <<"("<< tx_data[1]<<")";
      cout<<endl;
      cout << "\n \n The TRANSMITTED DATA is: ";
      for(k=15;k>0;k--)
        cout << tx_data[k];
      cout << endl;
      err_bito=((8*r4o)+(4*r3o)+(2*r2o)+(1*r1o)); // ERROR BIT GENERATED
      for(k=15;k>0;k--)
        rx_data[k]=tx_data[k];
      if(rx_data[err_bito]==1)
        rx_data[err_bito]=0;
      else
        rx_data[err_bito]=1;
      cout << "\n \n The Received DATA WITH ERROR is:";
      for(k=15;k>0;k--)
        cout << rx_data[k];
      cout << endl;
      if(rx_data[3]==1){
        r1++;
        r2++;
      }
      if(rx_data[5]==1){
        r1++;
        r3++;
      }
      if(rx_data[6]==1){
        r2++;
        r3++;
      }
      if(rx_data[7]==1){
        r1++;
        r2++;
        r3++;
      }
      if(rx_data[9]==1){
        r1++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(rx_data[10]==1){
        r2++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(rx_data[11]==1){
        r1++;
        r2++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(rx_data[12]==1){
        r3++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(rx_data[13]==1){
        r1++;
        r3++;
        r4++;
      }
      if(rx_data[14]==1){
        r2++;
        r3++;
        r4++;
      }if(rx_data[15]==1){
        r1++;
        r2++;
        r3++;
        r4++;
      }
      r1n=r1%2;
      r2n=r2%2;
      r3n=r3%2;
      r4n=r4%2;
      r1=r2=r3=r4=0;
      if(r1o==r1n){
        if(r2o==r2n){
          if(r3o==r3n){
            if(r4o==r4n)
              cout << "\n \n No Error" << endl;
            else
              cout << "\n \n Not Possible" << endl;
          }else{
            if(r4o==r4n)
              cout << "\n \n Not Possible" << endl;
            else{
              err_bitn=12;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 12" << endl;
            }
          }
        }else{
          if(r3o==r3n){
            if(r4o==r4n)
              cout << "\n \n Not Possible" << endl;
            else{
              err_bitn=10;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 10" << endl;
            }
          }else{
            if(r4o==r4n){
              err_bitn=6;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 6" << endl;
            }else{
              err_bitn=14;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 14" << endl;
            }
          }
        }
      }else{
        if(r2o==r2n){
          if(r3o==r3n){
            if(r4o==r4n)
              cout << "\n \n Not Possible" << endl;
            else{
              err_bitn=9;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 9" << endl;
            }
          }else{
            if(r4o==r4n){
              err_bitn=5;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 5" << endl;
            }else{
              err_bitn=13;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 13" << endl;
            }
          }
        }else{
          if(r3o==r3n){
            if(r4o==r4n){
              err_bitn=3;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 3" << endl;
            }else{
              err_bitn=11;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 11" << endl;
            }
          }else{
            if(r4o==r4n){
              err_bitn=7;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 7" << endl;
            }else{
              err_bitn=15;
              cout << "\n \n Error in bit 15" << endl;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if(rx_data[err_bitn]==1)
        rx_data[err_bitn]=0;
      else
        rx_data[err_bitn]=1;
      cout << "\n \n The CORRECTED DATA is: ";
      for(k=15;k>0;k--)
        cout << rx_data[k];
      cout << endl;
      bits[11]=rx_data[15];
      bits[10]=rx_data[14];
      bits[9]=rx_data[13];
      bits[8]=rx_data[12];
      bits[7]=rx_data[11];
      bits[6]=rx_data[10];
      bits[5]=rx_data[9];
      bits[4]=rx_data[7];
      bits[3]=rx_data[6];
      bits[2]=rx_data[5];
      bits[1]=rx_data[3];
      cout << "\n \n The Received data withot redundant bit is: ";
      for(k=11;k>0;k--)
        cout << bits[k];
      cout << endl;
      double x=2;
      double number=0;
      for(k=11;k>0;k--){
        double z=0;
        z=pow(x, k-1);
        double temp=0;
        temp=bit[k]*z;
        number=number+temp;
      }
      cout << "\n \n The ALPHABET entered was: " << one_char << endl;
    }else{
      if(alp==2){
        int num,numb,err_bito,err_bitn;
        int bit[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int bits[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        cout << "\n \n THIS NUMERIC ERROR DETECTION AND CORRECTIONPROGRAM" << endl;
        cout<<"\n \n*******************************************************************************";
        cout<<"\n -:CAUTION:- ";
        cout<<"\n \n SINCE THE PROGRAM HAS BEEN DESIGNED FOR 11BITARRAY,THE PROGRAM WILL NOT ACCEPT ANY VALUES GREATER THAN OREQUAL 2048";
        cout<<"\n \n*******************************************************************************";
        cout << "\n \n \n Enter any decimal number: ";
        cin >> numb;
        if(numb<2048)
          num=numb;
        else{
          cout << "\n" << endl;
          cout << "If u carry on u will get erroneous results" <<endl;
        }
        bit[1]=num%2;
        int a;
        a=num-num%2;
        int b=a/2;
        bit[2]=b%2;
        a=b-b%2;
        b=a/2;
        bit[3]=b%2;
        a=b-b%2;
        b=a/2;
        bit[4]=b%2;
        a=b-b%2;
        b=a/2;
        bit[5]=b%2;
        a=b-b%2;
        b=a/2;
        bit[6]=b%2;
        a=b-b%2;
        b=a/2;
        bit[7]=b%2;
        a=b-b%2;
        b=a/2;
        bit[8]=b%2;
        a=b-b%2;
        b=a/2;
        bit[9]=b%2;
        a=b-b%2;
        b=a/2;
        bit[10]=b%2;
        a=b-b%2;
        b=a/2;
        bit[11]=b%2;
        a=b-b%2;
        b=a/2;
        cout << "\n \n The equivalent binary data is:";
        for( k=11;k>0;k--)
          cout << bit[k];
        cout << endl;
        int r1,r2,r3,r4,r1o,r2o,r3o,r4o,r1n,r2n,r3n,r4n;
        r1=r2=r3=r4=r1o=r2o=r3o=r4o=r1n=r2n=r3n=r4n=0;
        if(bit[1]==1){
          r1++;
          r2++;
        }
        if(bit[2]==1){
          r1++;
          r3++;
        }
        if(bit[3]==1){
          r2++;
          r3++;
        }
        if(bit[4]==1){
          r1++;
          r2++;
          r3++;
        }
        if(bit[5]==1){
          r1++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(bit[6]==1){
          r2++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(bit[7]==1){
          r1++;
          r2++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(bit[8]==1){
          r3++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(bit[9]==1){
          r1++;
          r3++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(bit[10]==1){
          r2++;
          r3++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(bit[11]==1){
          r1++;
          r2++;
          r3++;
          r4++;
        }
        r1o=r1%2;
        r2o=r2%2;
        r3o=r3%2;
        r4o=r4%2;
        cout<<"\n \n The REDUNDENT BITS are: ";
        cout << r1o << r2o << r3o << r4o << endl;
        r1=r2=r3=r4=0;
        int tx_data[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int rx_data[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        cout<<"\n \n Data with REDUNDANTS BITS are:";
        tx_data[15]=bit[11];
        cout<< tx_data[15];
        tx_data[14]=bit[10];
        cout<< tx_data[14];
        tx_data[13]=bit[9];
        cout<< tx_data[12];
        tx_data[12]=bit[8];
        cout<< tx_data[12];
        tx_data[11]=bit[7];
        cout<< tx_data[11];
        tx_data[10]=bit[6];
        cout<< tx_data[10];
        tx_data[9]=bit[5];
        cout<< tx_data[9];
        tx_data[8]=r4o;
        cout<<"("<< tx_data[8]<<")";
        tx_data[7]=bit[4];
        cout<< tx_data[7];
        tx_data[6]=bit[3];
        cout<< tx_data[6];
        tx_data[5]=bit[2];
        cout<< tx_data[5];
        tx_data[4]=r3o;
        cout<<"("<< tx_data[4]<<")";
        tx_data[3]=bit[1];
        cout<< tx_data[3];
        tx_data[2]=r2o;
        cout<<"("<< tx_data[2]<<")";
        tx_data[1]=r1o;
        cout<<"("<< tx_data[1]<<")";
        cout<<endl;
        cout << "\n \n The TRANSMITTED DATA is: ";
        for(k=15;k>0;k--)
          cout << tx_data[k];
        cout << endl;
        err_bito=((8*r4o)+(4*r3o)+(2*r2o)+(1*r1o)); // ERROR BIT GENERATED
        for(k=15;k>0;k--)
          rx_data[k]=tx_data[k];
        if(rx_data[err_bito]==1)
          rx_data[err_bito]=0;
        else
          rx_data[err_bito]=1;
        cout << "\n \n The Received DATA WITH ERROR is:";
        for(k=15;k>0;k--)
          cout << rx_data[k];
        cout << endl;
        if(rx_data[3]==1){
          r1++;
          r2++;
        }
        if(rx_data[5]==1){
          r1++;
          r3++;
        }
        if(rx_data[6]==1){
          r2++;
          r3++;
        }
        if(rx_data[7]==1){
          r1++;
          r2++;
          r3++;
        }
        if(rx_data[9]==1){
          r1++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(rx_data[10]==1){
          r2++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(rx_data[11]==1){
          r1++;
          r2++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(rx_data[12]==1){
          r3++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(rx_data[13]==1){
          r1++;
          r3++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(rx_data[14]==1){
          r2++;
          r3++;
          r4++;
        }
        if(rx_data[15]==1){
          r1++;
          r2++;
          r3++;
          r4++;
        }
        r1n=r1%2;
        r2n=r2%2;
        r3n=r3%2;
        r4n=r4%2;
        r1=r2=r3=r4=0;
        if(r1o==r1n){
          if(r2o==r2n){
            if(r3o==r3n){
              if(r4o==r4n)
                cout << "\n \n No Error" << endl;
              else
                cout << "\n \n Not Possible" << endl;
            }else{
              if(r4o==r4n)
                cout << "\n \n Not Possible" << endl;
              else{
                err_bitn=12;
                cout << "\n \n Error in bit 12" << endl;
              }
            }
          }else{
            if(r3o==r3n){
              if(r4o==r4n)
                cout << "\n \n Not Possible" << endl;
              else{
                err_bitn=10;
                cout << "\n \n Error in bit 10" << endl;
              }
            }else{
              if(r4o==r4n){
                err_bitn=6;
                cout << "\n \n Error in bit 6" << endl;
              }else{
                err_bitn=14;
                cout << "\n \n Error in bit 14" << endl;
              }
            }
          }
        }else{
          if(r2o==r2n){
            if(r3o==r3n){
              if(r4o==r4n)
                cout << "\n \n Not Possible" << endl;
              else{
                err_bitn=9;
                cout << "\n \n Error in bit 9" << endl;
              }
            }else{
              if(r4o==r4n){
                err_bitn=5;
                cout << "\n \n Error in bit 5" << endl;
              }else{
                err_bitn=13;
                cout << "\n \n Error in bit 13" << endl;
              }
            }
          }else{
            if(r3o==r3n){
              if(r4o==r4n){
                err_bitn=3;
                cout << "\n \n Error in bit 3" << endl;
              }else{
                err_bitn=11;
                cout << "\n \n Error in bit 11" << endl;
              }
            }else{
              if(r4o==r4n){
                err_bitn=7;
                cout << "\n \n Error in bit 7" << endl;
              }else{
                err_bitn=15;cout << "\n \n Error in bit 15" << endl;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if(rx_data[err_bitn]==1)
          rx_data[err_bitn]=0;
        else
          rx_data[err_bitn]=1;
        cout << "\n \n The CORRECTED DATA is: ";
        for(k=15;k>0;k--)
          cout << rx_data[k];
        cout << endl;
        bits[11]=rx_data[15];
        bits[10]=rx_data[14];
        bits[9]=rx_data[13];
        bits[8]=rx_data[12];
        bits[7]=rx_data[11];
        bits[6]=rx_data[10];
        bits[5]=rx_data[9];
        bits[4]=rx_data[7];
        bits[3]=rx_data[6];
        bits[2]=rx_data[5];
        bits[1]=rx_data[3];
        cout << "\n \n The Recieved data without redundant bit is: ";
        for(k=11;k>0;k--)
          cout << bits[k];
        cout << endl;
        double x=2;
        double number=0;
        for(k=11;k>0;k--){
          double z=0;
          z=pow(x, k-1);
          double temp=0;
          temp=bit[k]*z;
          number=number+temp;
        }
        cout << "\n \n The decimal number entered was:" << number << endl;
      }else{
        cout<<"You are quiting from the program";
      }
    }
  }while(alp!=3);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: There is no such header `iostream.h`

Comment: You should use cycles such as `for` or `while` instead of copypasting.

Comment: If the class is C programming, this code is a definite fail as the code is C++.   You've used a lot of "copy and paste" of code, rather than a loop, and used a series of variable like `r1`, `r2`, .... where an array operated on with a loop will probably be easier for a mere mortal - like a professor - to understand.   In short, the code is dreadful style, which is difficult to understand, and quite possibly difficult to determine if it works correctly.

Comment: afaik `main()` isnt valid `c++`, also the code as posted here wont compile (for other reasons). Please fix it, because that code doesnt seem ok at all

Comment: @MAKRipon how is that code OK? It does not compile

Comment: So should I re-write the hole code or some twinkling could do the rest. As I'm still beginner in C++.

Comment: @M.M looks like they wrote it for turbo-C or VC6 <.<

Comment: you should rewrite the question, because it isnt clear. One needs at least input, output and expected output and a code that can compile to reproduce the problem

Comment: this isn't hamming code correction, it's an oibfuscated attempt to illustrate how it might work..  noone would in real life to  turn byte or word into array of integers representing bits.. there are bit-wise operations  to handle it.

Comment: You need to split your big long pile of code into subroutines.

Comment: Take a look at [mcve] and try clean up the code